# How to simplify tensor expression with symbolic coeficients?

Tags: vector, tensors

I can use `Vectors` to simplify the following expression:

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c) ∈ Vectors[3];
TensorReduce[3 b.a\[Cross]c - 3 c.b\[Cross]a]
```

which gives me 0, and correct.

However, if I change the value "3" into a symbol "g", it fails:

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c) ∈ Vectors[3];
TensorReduce[g b.a\[Cross]c - g c.b\[Cross]a]
```

Or

```
$Assumptions = (a | b | c) ∈ Vectors[3];
$Assumptions = g ∈ Reals;
TensorReduce[g b.a\[Cross]c - g c.b\[Cross]a]
```

Mathematica gives me $g b.a\times c-g c.b\times a$, which should be 0 as well.

How can I do this simplification in Mathematica?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$Assumptions = {(a | b | c) ∈ Vectors[3], g ∈ Reals}

TensorReduce[g b.a\[Cross]c - g c.b\[Cross]a]
```

> 0

Answer (score 6):

```
$Assumptions=(a|b|c) ∈ Vectors[3] && g ∈ Reals

TensorReduce[g b.a\[Cross]c-g c.b\[Cross]a]
(*0*)
```

g doesn't have to be `Reals`. `Complexes` works too.  It just can't be something totally undefined.